Why does turbo use http instead of https?
I have a symfony login. My page uses turbo and is served with an ngninx reverse proxy that terminates the https. caddy with frankenphp serves the page over http:80.
The problem is that locally when caddy serves over https the login works. But in my deployment i get this error:

Mixed Content: The page at 'https://domain/login' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure resource 'http://domain/login'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

I expect the submission of the form to https and not http

I'm guessing it is using HTTP because that's what the site is running since Nginx is terminating HTTPS. You could try explicitly settings the scheme and possibly host: https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-5-1-simpler-request-context

I fixed it by configure the reverse proxyin symfony by setting:
trusted_proxies: 127.0.0.0/8,10.0.0.0/8,172.16.0.0/12,192.168.0.0/16
trusted_hosts: '%env(TRUSTED_HOSTS)%'
trusted_headers: ['x-forwarded-proto', 'x-forwarded-for']

in the framework.yaml
